# Como ajustar la barra del scroll ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb

Tags: html, css

Necesito ajustar la barra de color rojo, para que sea mas pequeña o poder cambiarlo por una imagen.

No se como hacerlo y por más que busco no lo consigo.

```css
#cont{
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #2F4F4F;
 width: 50%;
 height: 50%;
 left: 25%;
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
.caja2 {
 position: initial;
 width: 100%;
 height: 10%;
 border-radius: 10px;
 background-color: #DCDCDC;
 padding-top: 2%;
 margin-top: 2%;

}

::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 25px;
    background-color:#4F4F4F;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:increment{
    height:40px;
    background-color:yellow;
    background-size:25px 40px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-button:vertical:decrement{
    height:40px;
    background-color:yellow;   
    background-size:25px 40px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: red;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 9px;
    background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Prueba</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <meta charset='utf-8'>
 
</script>
</head>
<body>
 <div id='cont'>
  <div class='caja2'>Caja1</div>
  <div class='caja2'>Caja2</div>
  <div class='caja2'>Caja3</div>
  <div class='caja2'>Caja4</div>
  <div class='caja2'>Caja5</div>
  <div class='caja2'>Caja6</div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: El problema de esto es que sólo te va a funcionar en navegadores webkit, en otros la barra va a seguir viéndose "normal" (sin estilos).

Comment: y que pseudoclase deberia utilizar para el chrome??

Answer (score 1):

Puedes agregar a tu hoja de estilos principal lo siguiente:

```
/* Cambiar estilo del scroll */
body::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 7px;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: #2196F3; /* color de la barra */
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Esto modificara las propiedades del `scroll` del `body`, por lo que si tienes un modal o algún otro elemento que contenga un `scroll` solo lo agregas en la lista de elementos seleccionados.

> NOTA: Por el momento los navegadores que utilizan webkit son los que tienen la compatibilidad
>   para manejar esto con css, firefox requiere del manejo con JS puedes
>   utilizar el siguiente tutorial:
>
> http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Queda asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]